# How to measure coverage in a proper way

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, coverage.py

Pytest + coverage are showing very strange coverage statistics.
They are counting only those modules where tests were added, but other Python modules are not calculated for some reason.

I have a simple Python Microservice with a structure similar to:

```
README.rst
Dockerfile
manage.py
api_service/
setup.py
requirements.txt
tests/
```

Where `api_service` contains all the logic, and `tests` contains unit tests.
API is written in Python 3.X
Unit tests - Pytest 3.10.0

I'm running these commands to get a code coverage statistics:

```
python coverage run pytest -v --junit-xml=junit-report.xml tests/
python coverage xml --fail-under 80
python coverage report
```

It shows really strange and unexpected results for me.
e.g. there are empty **init**.py modules in the final report (with 100% coverage) and they affects the final coverage percentage.
Also, it adds a lot of modules with just abstract classes, etc.

But what is really not expected at all - it's not counting Python modules without tests. It's awful!

Are there any commands, flags etc. to handle this situation is a proper way?

I've tried also to run something like:

```
python coverage run --source=service_api -v --junit-xml=junit-report.xml tests/
```

But it also returns not expected results.

Comment: I would have said to use `--source`, but you've already done that.  Though you didn't say how those results were unexpected.  What is wrong with those results?  About the \_\_init\_\_.py and abstract class files: Python files are executed when imported. Coverage.py can't distinguish between class definitions and "real" code: it's all code execution.

Comment: You say the source dir is named `api_service/`, but using `--source=service_api`? Please add a [mcve] so it can be reproduced locally.

Answer (score 2):

CD into prj directory and run:

```
pytest --cov=. tests/ --cov-report xml
```

in order to get the code coverage for your source files in xml format.

prereq:

```
pip install pytest pytest-cov
```